# Problem in understanding big-O notation and similiar

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to understand the concept of big-O notation problem and came through this problem. Can you tell me how could

> $$O(n) = 1 + \Theta(1/n)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$O(n)$ is the set of all functions $f(n)$ such that, for sufficiently large $n$ and a positive constant $c$, $f(n) \le cn$.

$1+\Theta(\frac{1}{n})$ is an abuse of notation that denotes the set of all functions $h(n) = 1+g(n)$ such that, for sufficiently large $n$ and a two positive constants $c_1$, $c_2$, $\frac{c_1}{n} \le g(n) \le \frac{c_2}{n}$.

Then the claim is clearly false since, e.g., the function $h(n)=n$ belongs to $O(n)$ but it does not belong to $1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Possibly typo: you need $\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: i do get what are you trying to say. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to understand notation like $f(n) = O(g(n))$ is that the equals sign is really wrong, it should be something like $f(n) \in O(g(n))$, the function $f$ belongs to a set of functions. That set is the set of functions $h$ such that for some constants $c > 0$ and $n_0$ it is $h(n) \le c g(n)$ whenever $n \ge n_0$ (this presumes non-negative functions, sprinkle absolute values over all if not). The equals sign is just too entrenched in usage to be changed (not that there haven't been tries).

A rule of thumb is that the right hand side is a less precise statement (in the  $f(n) = O(g(n))$ case, a single function as opposed to a set of functions).

A useful extension is to say e.g. $f(n) = n^2 + O(g(n))$ to state that there is a function $h$ so that $f(n) = n^2 + h(n)$ where $h(n) = O(g(n))$. One reason why we use $=$ instead of $\in$ is that it makes sense in sequences like:

$\begin{align*}
   5 n^2 + 3 n + 4
     &= 5 n^2 + O(3 n) \\
     &= 5 n^2 + O(n) \\
     &= O(n^2)
 \end{align*}$

Note that $O(n) = O(n^2)$, but **not** $O(n^2) = O(n)$.

The notation $f(n) =\Theta(g(n))$ says $f$ is such that there are constants $n_0$ and $c_2 \ge c_1 > 0$ so that if $n \ge n_0$ then $c_1 g(n) \le f(n) \le c_2 g(n)$.

Intuitively, $n = 1 + \Theta(1/n)$ means that $n$ doesn't stray too far from $1$, and the difference goes down as $n$ increases. This is clearly nonsense.

Hildebrand's ["A Short Course on Asymptotics"](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/lecture-notes/asymptotics.pdf) elaborates quite a bit on this (and related) notations and their manipulation.